# Recursive descent parser with backtracking for the grammar $S \rightarrow aSa\ |\ aa$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

Can someone enlighten me why a recursive descent parser with backtracking that tries the productions $S \rightarrow aSa$ and $S \rightarrow aa$ (in that order) does not recognize the language formed by the grammar $S \rightarrow aSa\ |\ aa$.

It appears to only parse words from the language $\{a^{2^n}\ |\ n \ge 1 \}$.

I generated such a parser using [this ABNF Parser Generator](http://coasttocoastresearch.com/interactiveapg) with the production rule `S = "a" S "a" / "aa"` and the parser does not recognize the word `aaaaaa`, for example.

I would expect it to use the production $S \rightarrow aSa$ until the concatenation of the parse tree's terminal nodes from the left starts with 7 `a`'s, and then go up the parse tree choosing the production $S \rightarrow aa$ instead until the tree looks like this:

```
   S 
 / | \
a  S  a
 / | \
a  S  a
  / \
 a   a
```

Comment: Why do you think it can't parse this word?

Comment: @Yuval, I think it should parse it, so I must be missing something.

Comment: Ah, now the question makes more sense; thanks for the edit! If what you write is true (I did not check) the generator seems to have a bug. (Or it is not specified for your grammar; I think this is unlikely since the grammar is elementary and unambiguous.

Comment: @Raphael, I edited the question again (hopefully without changing the meaning). I'm actually tasked to explain why such a parser doesn't recognize the word `aaaaaa`.

Comment: Where did you get that tree. I do not get much from that ABNF parser generator. The tree you give does not make much sense. But the string `aaaaaa` should parse and does not. But `aaaa` does parse. You are apparently right about powers of 2.  The thing must be bugged. it parses only `aa` with `S =  "aa" / "a" [S] "a"`.  Can you trace what the parser does?

Comment: @babou, That's just the parse tree I'd expect to be constructed for `aaaaaa`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually a property of the "singleton match strategy" usual in naive implementations of recursive descent parsers with backtracking.

I'll quote [this answer](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.compilers/c/Rr78g1zK6mE/m/EGcSu5YaK68J) by Dr Adrian Johnstone:

> The trick here is to realise that many backtracking parsers use what
> we call a singleton match strategy, in which as soon as the parse
> function for a rule finds a match, it returns. In general, parse
> functions need to return a set of putative matches. Just try working
> it through, and you'll see that a singelton match parser misses some
> of the possible derivations.

Also, this image available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49465845/5915941) on StackOverflow will help to visualize what's happening in the case you exemplified:

[image: How recursive descent parser with backtracking fails by using singleton match strategy]

Answer (score 6):

This is not much of an answer, but the parse trees do not fit the
normal comments.

Your grammar $S \rightarrow aSa\ |\ aa$ should parse the string
$aaaaaa$.

But the parse tree has the following form:

```
      S 
     /|\
    / S \
   / /|\ \
  / / S \ \
 / / / \ \ \
a a a   a a a
```

or if you prefer this presentation, with the terminals on different
lines

```
     S 
   / | \
  a  S  a
   / | \
  a  S  a
    / \
   a   a
```

I checked that the ABNF parser generator does not seem to work, but I
do not know how to trace what it does.

It indeed seems to recongnize the set  $\{a^{2^n}\ |\ n \ge 1 \}$ wich
is not what the grammar defines.

It is a bit surprising to have such an elaborate site around a buggy parser,
which furthermore uses a totally uninteresting parsing technique.

---

After a further look at it:

I think I found one source of the problem. The square brackets mean
*optional*.

So your grammar should be written either 
`S = "a" S "a" / "aa"`
or `S = "a" [S] "a"`. Then it seems to work correctly.

But the system is apparently lost when having twice the same rule in
different forms. I am not sure why.

I did not find a page explaining these syntactic issues for specifying
the grammar.

I still consider that buggy.

Comment: Ouch. Yeah. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that parse tree. I'll edit my question and paste yours.

Comment: I did find another recursive descent, backtracking parser generator with an online demo [here](http://rpatk.net/web/en/parsecustom.php) and it shows the same behaviour with this rule: `S ::= 'a'<S>'a' | 'a''a'`

Comment: It still doesn't parse `aaaaaa` when using `S = "a" S "a" / "aa"`, but you seem to be right about the brackets.

Comment: I do not see the point of exploring recursive descent, backtracking parser.

Comment: you are right about `S = "a" S "a" / "aa"` ... I tested too fast, and clicked on generate instead of parse.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a very simple implementation of this parser in C++ (see below), and it has the same issue. This seems to be because whenever the function `s1()` for the production $S \rightarrow aSa$ returns `true`, `s()` will immediately return and never try `s2()` (the function implementing $S \rightarrow aa$) for that node of the parse tree.

Consider parsing the word `aaaaaa` again. At one point, the parse tree will look like this:

```
   S 
 / | \
a  S  a
 / | \
a  S  a    <--
 / | \
a  S  a
  / \
 a   a
```

Then, `s()` will return `true` for the `S`-node at the 3rd level and the production $S \rightarrow aa$ will never be considered here, but instead one level higher, resulting in:

```
   S 
 / | \
a  S  a
  / \
 a   a
```

I tend to consider this an issue with my implementation and not with backtracking recursive descent parsers in general, though.

```
#include <iostream>

char* next;    
bool term(char token) {
    if (*next != '\0')
        return *next++ == token;
    else
        return false;
}

bool s();    
bool s1() {
    return term('a') && s() && term('a');
}    
bool s2() {
    return term('a') && term('a');
}    
bool s() {
    auto save = next;
    return s1() or (next = save, s2());
}    

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    next = "aaaaaa";
    if (s() && *next == '\0') {
        std::cout << "match";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "no match";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### **It is a feature not a bug**

Have a close look at when & where backtracking occurs:

```
     1.           2.          3.          4.          5.          6.          7.          8.          9.          10.         11.         12.

     S            S           S           S           S           S           S           S           S           S           S           S      
   / | \        / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \
  a  S  a      a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a
                / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       /   \
               a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a     a
                            / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \
                           a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a
                                        / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       /   \
                                       a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a     a
                                                    / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       / | \       /   \
                                                   a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a     a
                                                                / | \       / | \       / | \       /   \   
                                                               a  S  a     a  S  a     a  S  a     a     a
                                                                            / | \       /   \
                                                                           a  S  a     a     a



w[] = 'aaaaaa'  //input
l[] = ''        //current tree leafs


 1. tree:   The parser starts with the start symbol S and tries first alternative S->aSa:       Result: w[0]  = l[0]     w = aaaaaa    l = aSa
 |          -- S->aSa works                                                                         | |     | | 
 6. tree:   The parser matches a after a:                                                       Result: w[6]  = l[6]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaaaaSaaaaaa
 7. tree:   The parser tries S->aSa again but there is no match!                                Result: w[7] != l[7]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaaaaaSaaaaaaa 
 8. tree:   The parser tries S->aa but there is still no match!                                 Result: w[7] != l[7]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 9. tree:   Backtracking after the last symbol that matched => Backtracking at l[7]             Result: w[7] != l[7]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaaaaaaaaaa
10. tree:   Backtracking after the last symbol that matched => Backtracking at l[7]             Result: w[7] != l[7]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaaaaaaaa
11. tree:   Backtracking after the last symbol that matched => Backtracking at l[7]             Result: w[7] != l[7]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaaaaaa
12. tree:   Backtracking after the last symbol that matched => Backtracking at l[7]             Result: w[7] != l[7]     w = aaaaaa    l = aaaa
```

**The crucial point here is that the parser backtracks after the position, where the last matching character was found.**
That's why it "jumps" from tree 11 with *l = aaaaaaaa* to the 12th tree with *l = aaaa* by using *S -> aa* at l[7].

Comment: Finally got time to edit it! ;)